# Rewrite homepage to main url

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have Magento configured to be running from a /`shop/` folder in a website build.  The main site is a WordPress wrapper to the shop.

As the homepage is above the Magento folder, ideally I'd like to redirect the Magento homepage (/shop/) back up to the main website homepage.

I.e

```
/shop/ -> /
/shop/en/ -> /
/shop/de/ -> /
```

Can this be achieved with the admin URL rewriting system (ideal) or would I be better off achieving this via htaccess/nginx config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably look at doing this through the nginx config, this is how we typically handle the rewrite from domain.com to www.domain.com.  This page give some pretty good ideas on how this can be handled

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224441/nginx-redirect-all-requests-from-subdirectory-to-another-subdirectory-root.